# RFID-RC522 unable to access sector after changing the key

Tags: key, rfid

I wrote in block 7 using serial monitor

FF FF FF 11 11 11
Now I am unable to access it. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover a MIFARE Classic card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745936/can-i-recover-a-mifare-classic-card)

Comment: Also see [Locking mechanism of Mifare Classic 1K](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27885861/2425802)